# How to create a barebones Phonegap project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am in the process of setting up headless, Ubuntu 14.04, server to enable me to automate (script) the process of producing Android APKs with Phonegap.  I have done the following

- Install Java JDK
- Install ANT
- Install the Android SDK
- Setup the environment path
- Created a test project following the instructions in the [Phonegap CLI documentation](http://phonegap.com/install/).
- Issued a `phonegap build android -d >> result.txt` to have the APK created under `/app-folder/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk'
- Moved the APK to a folder on my Dropbox
- Opened, installed and tested the APK on my Android phone

All crystal clear and pretty smooth sailing.  However, here is where I run into several unknowns.

1. The `/app-folder/config.xml' file is relatively easy to understand but it would still be nice to have a comprehensive resource or cheatsheet that explains all the stuff I can put in config.xml.  The Phonegap docs are helpful but a succinct cheatsheet would be nicer.  I haven't been able to find one.
2. Ultimately, I want to build my own APKs.  Just how should I go about that without starting from scratch.  Can I use the default Hello World project and do the following

xxx

1. Change the name, description and author attributes in config.xml
2. Replace the #dpi and port-#dpi images
3. Bind to the `load`, `deviceready` `offline` and `online` events to do my own stuff
4. Do what with the various `allow-intent` fields?
5. Do what with the various files in the `spec` sub folder?

Finally, I imagine that using all the various plugins that are there in the config.xml file for the hello world app

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

is liable to bloat the app so I assume I should be more selective about what I leave behind there on a per-app basis?  And last but not the least just how do I go about modifying this basic app to sign it for the real world?

I only got started on this process about 6 hours ago and am quite surprised that thus far it has turned out to be so easy.  However, I have been unable to find any tutorials that go further than telling me how to install phonegap-cli and then build hello world.

I would much appreciate any help and tips.

---

I have since discovered that one can create a barebones Phonegap app in the CLI starting from one of many templates.  You can view the templates on offer  by issuing

```
phonegap template list
```

The `jquery-mobile-starter` template I have found is a decent starting point.  Some progress but I still haven't figured out which of the config.xml settings - particularly the plugin and allow-intent ones I need to modify on a per app basis depending on what it is being used for so I would still appreciate help here.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link to a similar question and answer I came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33338203/1640892). But I ultimately used PhoneGap Build. Which to me seems to make more sense and seems to be a more streamlined solution than both Cordova and PhoneGap.

[Here is a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOjoNEUFeVE) and [source code for a Hello World, fully functioning starter app](https://github.com/ccoenraets/EmployeeDirectory) for PhoneGap Build.

#### Instructions:

1. Download [source code](https://github.com/ccoenraets/EmployeeDirectory).
2. Zip downloaded folder.
3. Upload .zip file to [build.phonegap.com/apps](http://build.phonegap.com/apps).
4. Click build button.
5. Scan QR code using your mobile device.
6. Download and install app on your mobile device.

The entire process takes about one minute to complete.

Comment: thankyou for the answer.  I had in the mean time figured out everything I needed to know to work with Phonegap CLI. I guess I should have deleted the question but had forgotten all about it.

Comment: @DroidOS: Or, even better, consider answering your own question with what you learned. Then accept your own answer. It might help the next guy!

Answer (score -1):

Look at [ionic](http://ionicframework.com)

Then head on to the getting started section and follow along. Make sure you have nodejs installed.

Comment: I don't downvote often or lightly.  But did you not notice that I want to automate APK builds on a headlesss server?  My questions are all related to that requirement and the consequent need to adapt a "template" application on the fly according to the needs of each individual APK that needs to be built. I am not looking for readymade UI components and the like.  Regrettably you do not in fact answer any of my questions.